# Question regarding commutativity of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transpose

Given,  $A, B, C$ be $2 \times2$  matrices with entries from the set of real numbers. Define $A*B = \frac{1}{2}(AB'+A'B)$ where $X'$ denotes the transpose of $X$. Does $A*B=B*A$?

My book answers this as yes, but I cannot understand why that would be, generally.

I can see from here, that, $$A*B = \frac{1}{2}(AB'+A'B)$$
and, $$B*A = \frac{1}{2}(BA'+B'A)$$

But, my understanding is that matrices $A, B$, in general, do not commute. So, in general, $AB' \neq B'A$ and $A'B \neq BA'$

So, how would $A*B=B*A?$ Can anyone justify the book's statement, or is it a mistake and I'm correct here?

Comment: You are right, in general $A*B\ne B*A$, however it is true that $(B*A)'=A*B$

Comment: Can you give a link to the book? It might be a typo, or you have overlooked the transpose.

Comment: @leoli1 Yes, but here, if you read my post, $*$ isnt defined as direct multiplication, but it is a newly defined operation.

Comment: @Techie5879 Yes, I was refering to that new operation

Comment: @DietrichBurde It's a question from an exercise, but I can show a picture. Its not available on the internet

Comment: Yes, that I also verified to be true. Just like the reversal law in normal multiplication it would be the case here too. But in general $A*B\neq B*A$. Thats what I wanted to verify. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can write down a counterexample to $A*B=B*A$ and prove that $(A*B)^T=B*A$, so everything is alright.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thats right. Thanks!